# Spring Boot - Multi Module and problem to find application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I have a monorepo with a parent POM and several modules. One of the modules (Module A) is a Spring Boot application that has a dependency on another module (Module B). Both have their respective application.properties files.

However, when Module A makes a call to Module B, an error occurs because the called module cannot find the values in its respective .properties file (using @Value).

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'kafka.bootstrap-servers' in value "${kafka.bootstrap-servers}"
```

Both properties are in the Spring applicationContext, but I believe the problem is that Module B does not manage the application.properties when the call comes from another module.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

**applicationContext A:**

[image]

**ApplicationContext B:**

[image]